# TYPO3 Exception - File does not exist

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Am getting an exception in fluid template as follows.

```
#1314516810: File /uploads/tx_sfel_sfel/img_uploads/ffffff.jpg/ does not exist.
```

This image is not present in the 'img_uploads' directory.

But I don't want to show this exception.

How to prevent the page from showing this error.

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried turning "displayErrors" (['SYS']['displayErrors']) off in the LocalConfiguration.php?

Comment: In LocalConfiguration.php changed ['SYS']['displayErrors'] as 0 show
"Oops, an error occurred!".....
I want to show this page without any error....

Comment: Maybe one of the following steps can help you: a) Add a 404-pagenotfound-handler ($TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = 'yourpagenotfoundscript.php'; $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_statheader'] = ‘HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found’;), b) run the scheduler tasks for the file abstraction layer, c) delete the sys_file_reference/sys_file entry manually from the database

Comment: Fixed it.
Added 'file_exists' condition in the controller to check whether the file exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can install VHS and use the Viewhelper  to check if there is this image. It will look like this:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
.
.
.
<v:media.exists file="{filepath}" >
         <f:then>
             [Your Image]
         </f:then>
</v:media.exists>
.
.
.
```